# is there a way to convert an object to an bytearray?

Tags: python, python-3.8

I have a class Packet is there a way to convert an object of it to an bytearray?

```
from abc import abstractmethod

class Packet:
    @abstractmethod
    def __init__(self, name, data):
        self.name = name
        self.data = data
```

```
packet = Packet("packet-01", None)
```

Comment: What do you want put into this `bytearray`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the `pickle` package to convert the object to. `bytearray`.

```
In [97]: from abc import abstractmethod 
    ...:  
    ...: class Packet: 
    ...:     @abstractmethod 
    ...:     def __init__(self, name, data): 
    ...:         self.name = name 
    ...:         self.data = data 
    ...:                                                                        

In [98]: packet = Packet('packet-01',None)                                      

In [99]: packet                                                                 
Out[99]: <__main__.Packet at 0x7f9d540cf040>

In [100]: import pickle                                                         

In [101]: byte = pickle.dumps(packet)                                           

In [102]: byte                                                                  
Out[102]: b'\x80\x04\x95:\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8c\x08__main__\x94\x8c\x06Packet\x94\x93\x94)\x81\x94}\x94(\x8c\x04name\x94\x8c\tpacket-01\x94\x8c\x04data\x94Nub.'
```

you can read about pickle [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html).